# C <> Java communication on multi platforms

Tags: java, c, communication

Is there any efficient way to let C programs talk to Java programs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X? I tried a simple TCP/IP-Server, but it causes a lot of CPU load.

Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: Take a look at [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

Comment: +1, but actually it highly depends on the task details. Have you tried to profile and investigate what gives the highest impact to the load?

Comment: Also you may try to use shared memory solutions, but again it's all depends on profiling and understanding what is the bottleneck. Without this you can't reliably say how to fix the issue.

Comment: Regarding accessing shared memory efficiently from Java. People from odnoklassniki.ru (a social network somewhat similar to, heh-heh, Facebook) told how they get a Java-based solution to serve 70K HTTP reqs/sec and 3000Mb/s on a 2x Intel Xeon E5620, 64 GB RAM using shared memory under Linux. Their story is at http://habrahabr.ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/148139/ (in Russian, but you can get the idea from code)

Comment: JNI isn't a choice, because it does not allow to let call Java methods from C. But the data are only some little ASCII texts (12 chars) but 250.000 per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cross-platform communication you can use sockets if the parties run on different computers, or, for local communication you can use memory-mapped files.

Properly written socket server should not cause too much CPU load, but it's easy to implement it wrong.

Our company offers [MsgConnect](https://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) product (free with source version is available), which hides complexities of building the transport and offers a simple SendMessage-like interface for inter-process communication on various platforms.

Comment: Memory-mapped files doesn't work on windows out-of-the-box. I'll see if my socket server is implemented wrong.

Comment: @mythbu MMFs work just perfectly on Windows, although they are not trivial to use right.

Answer (score 0):

The gold standard for these things is [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).